# systemverilog: Using structure as slice specifier in streaming operations

Tags: system-verilog

```
typedef struct {
bit y;
bit x;
} t_my_unpkd_struct;

t_my_unpkd_struct a[1:0];
bit [1:0] bb[1:0];

assign { >> {a} } = { << t_my_unpkd_struct {bb} };
```

The above code won't compile - what am I doing wrong? Can't I use a structure as a slice specifier?

BTW, my intention is to get:

```
a[0].x = bb[1][0]
a[0].y = bb[1][1]
a[1].x = bb[0][0]
a[1].y = bb[0][1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the `struct` `packed` and replace `{ >> {a} }`  with `a`:

```
typedef struct packed {
bit y;
bit x;
} t_my_unpkd_struct;

t_my_unpkd_struct a[1:0];
bit [1:0] bb[1:0];

assign a = { << t_my_unpkd_struct {bb} };
```

Simple test-bench for proof:

```
bit clk; always #5ns clk++;
default clocking cb @(posedge clk);
endclocking
initial begin
    repeat(20) begin
        @(negedge clk);
        void'(randomize(bb));
    end
    #10ns;
    $finish(2);
end
assert property (a[0].x == bb[1][0]);
assert property (a[0].y == bb[1][1]);
assert property (a[1].x == bb[0][0]);
assert property (a[1].y == bb[0][1]);
```

---

Updated:
The following works with an unpacked struct:

```
assign a = { << 2 {bb} };
```

or

```
always_comb { << 2 {a} } = { << t_my_unpkd_struct {bb} };
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to know if there is a solution if 'a' is to remain unpacked. I tried 

assign { >> t_my_unkpd_struct {a} } = { << t_my_unkpd_struct {bb} };

but that didn't work either

Comment: Why is the code different for the 'assign' vs 'always_comb'? I would like to understand the significance of that. I also hope to try using a parameter instead of '2' in your equations - I suppose that should work as well

Comment: There should not be a difference between `always_comb` and `assign` in this context; `always @*` would work too. One simulator I tested it on gave an internal failure with `assign {<<2{a}}`, which is a bug and using `always_comb` was my workaround.

Comment: So, would the following have worked?
always_comb a = { << 2 {bb} };

Comment: Yes, `always_comb a={<<{bb}};` should work. If not, then you have found a bug or limitation of your simulator.